Worksheet.row_dimensions type hinting does not work properly?
Worksheet's row_dimensions raises a Warning when I put an integer in it (for the index of the row to change the height of) although it works (height is changed and script runs correctly).
MRE:
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet

# Load an existing workbook or create a new one
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('your_workbook.xlsx')
ws: Worksheet = wb.active

# Set the height of row 1 to 25
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 25  <-- problem

# Save the changes back to the workbook
wb.save('your_workbook.xlsx')

I'm not allowed such warnings, nor am I allowed to add #noqa.
I'm using Python 3.11.1 and the latest version of openpyxl (3.1.2).


I'm not sure why these warnings exist at all: openpyxl is not typed. If you're using stubs, they don't look great: row_dimensions is typed there as a DimensionHolder, that symbol is not imported, and implementation uses a dict). Add an ignore comment and go on, maybe also report a bug in openpyxl-stubs (repo link above)

The implementation file was last edited 9 years ago, even before the stubs repo was created (and typing became mainstream), so this is not a version conflict - just a mistake.

@STerliakov I think the stubs in question are those in typeshed.

@InSync ough. I must have checked that. Those are in much better shape, but row_dimensions type is still incorrect, DimensionHolder is only for column_dimensions in the implementation. Now definitely worth a ticket, 'cause the rest looks fine, and so it's a minor bug instead of "looks like it shouldn't work in most cases" and can be fixed trivially. The code in question is correct and matches expected usage.

@STerliakov A ticket on openpyxl webiste / on their github?

As InSync clarified above, neither: that stubs package is dead and outdated, ticket should go to typeshed's github issues - recent stubs for openpyxl are part of typeshed. row_dimensions var is annotated incorrectly there - should be some dictionary, not a DimensionHolder.

It was a typeshed bug. Issue was created, fixed (not by me), and closed. https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/11845.
